# Images in CSS not loading while using Bundling in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am new to MVC4 and Bundling concepts. For me CSS file is loading properly , but the images specified in it not loaading and it shows 404 exception for it.

My CSS folder structure is: ~\Content\css\CustomCss\green.css

Images for CSS folder structure : Content\css\Customcss\Images\green.png

But while checking in net panel of Firebug, it shows the path for images as : /Content/css/CustomCSS/Content/css/Customcss/Images/Greenish.png

I don't know how this bundling refers images in CSS.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/CustomCss/css").Include("~/Content/css/CustomCss/Syncfusion-Grid-Greenish.css"));
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
 @Styles.Render(" ~/Content/css/CustomCSS/css")
```

Suggest me any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: you have a leading space in `@Styles.Render` tag of Layout.cshtml. Please remove and check may be it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer after a small struggle.

I just replaced the image url as ' images/Greenish_sprite.png ' instead of 'Content/css/Customcss/images/Greenish_sprite.png'.

It is working well now :)